# WPF Toolkit Chart Performance

Tags: lineseries

I have a chart with multiple line series (let's say 10).  Each line series is comprised of about 2,000 points.  Does anyone know why it takes MINUTES for the chart to render?  Is this simply how poorly this control behaves?

I've found that removing the points increases performance 10-fold.  However; I want to see the data points. See below how I have removed the data points...

```
        Style pointStyle = new Style(typeof(LineDataPoint));
        pointStyle.TargetType = typeof(System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint);
        pointStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TemplateProperty, null));
        pointStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(LineDataPoint.BackgroundProperty, model.LineColor));
        series.DataPointStyle = pointStyle;
```

The line where I set the TemplateProperty to null is what made the chart perform so quickly.

Any alternatives which still display the data points?